# TempTable Memory Storage Engine Issue

Tags: mysql-8.0, aws-aurora

I have a db.r5.2xlarge (64GB) AWS Aurora-MySQL instance (8.0.26 equivalent) and I have a long-running SQL which gives this error: `ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 1: The table '/rdsdbdata/tmp/#sqlfe_130_0' is full`.

When I switch the `internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine` variable to `Memory` and adjust `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` to a maximum value, the SQL runs without any error.

But I like to get this SQL running where `internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine` is using `TempTable`. When I switch the variable `temptable_max_ram` to 10GB, I still get the temporary disk full error.

When I switch the variable to 100GB, the CPU spikes up and basically my query is killed which is probably because the instance has only a maximum of 64GB RAM. So, I tried to switch this variable to 50GB, and still I get the temporary disk full error.

Does anyone know what I can to get this SQL running where the `internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine` is `TempTable`?

EDIT: I got this working by playing with the variable `temptable_max_mmap` instead.